How to get Tag inner text and Attribute value in the same loop and row HtmlAgilityPack C#
Following is the HTML i am working on; (C# project)
</TR>

  <TR>

    `<TD ALIGN="center">  <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="f0" VALUE="14652 4-76-17-7-2024-R" ONCLICK=uncheck("f0")>  &nbsp;</TD>

    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>

    <TD>76/07-17</TD>

    <TD>14652</TD>

    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>

    <TD>9.3</TD>

    <TD> 78 </TD>

    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>

    <TD>&nbsp;</TH>

  </TR>


I can get the tr[td] inner text via a loop.
But in the same loop I can not access the "input" attributes (Name / Value) to extract values as a array to maintain data integrity.
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(page);


 foreach (var row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[td]")) //textBox5.Text
 {
     table.Rows.Add(row.SelectNodes("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray());
      
     string namee1 = row.InnerText;
     
     //These works but without the attribute details.

     string Code_num = row.SelectSingleNode("//td//input").Attributes["value"].Value;

    // this gives only the first value without looping.
     
     MessageBox.Show(namee);

     
 }

Code_num - gives me the first value only without looping through the document.
Attributes dose not pick and I only get null reference. I am not that familiar with linq. Prefer help from xpath if possible.
Appreciate your help!!! Thank in Advance
Desired Out put  as follows;
Col 1 / Col 2/ col3 / col 4 / col5 / col6 / col 7 / col 8 /col9 / col10 / col/11
&nbsp /  /76/07-17/14652/&nbsp/9.3/ 78 /&nbsp/&nbsp /F0 / 14652 4-76-17-7-2024-R
Expected Output

It's not clear to me what result you are after. You should include an example of your desired output. I can see some problems, though. Evaluating //td//input in the context of your row variable would return every input contained within a td, anywhere in the document, not just within that td, because the XPath starts with //. You probably want to start it with .//, I imagine. Also, your HTML is not well formed. Does it really say **NAME**="f0"?

what is "inner value"?

Hi @ConalTuohy I have included a desired output picture for reference
there is no ** marks around 'name' and 'value'. Some how it has got there during posting to Stack.
.// gives me null reference all the time.
All what i need to do is put the above data td (Inner text) to table format. In the same row to include the Input attribute values (name and Value)

@tacoshy sorry its "inner text"!

If you want to select the input element relative to its parent td you can just use the XPath input

Thanks @ConalTuohy.
will you be able to elaborate with code?

@ConalTuohy I figure it out thanks. There was null exception due to formating issues in HTML file. Now sorted. Thanks

The following worked for me! There was null reference blocking my code as earlier values are not complete.
Hope this helps someone!!
 foreach (var row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[td]")) 
 {
                        
     string pos = "0";
                         
    pos = row.SelectSingleNode("td//input")?.Attributes["name"].Value;
    string injid = row.SelectSingleNode("td//input")?.Attributes["value"].Value;

     table.Rows.Add((row.SelectNodes("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray()));

 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pos))
 {
     
 }
 else
 {
     int ronum = table.Rows.Count - 1;
    
     DataRow dr = table.Rows[ronum];
     dr[9] = pos;

 }

 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(injid))
 {

 }
 else
 {
     int ronum = table.Rows.Count - 1;
  
     DataRow dr = table.Rows[ronum];
     dr[10] = injid;

 }
}

